# How should I set up a server sent event for Vuejs?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, axios

Could someone help me with advice on how to set up a **server sent event**?

I made a small bidding app in which the `auctionedItems` appear in the following component:

```
<div v-for="item in auctionedItems">
  <Item :info="item"></Item>
</div>
```

The `auctionedItems` array comes from a server (Express.js) `get` response. Each `auctionedItem`contains the `maximumBid`value.

Imagine someone bids on one of the Items => the `maximumBid`of the `auctionedItem`is changed in the server and is broadcasted to the users.

How would I set it up in Vue and in Express?

Comment: I think [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) would help, but not too familiar with them. A real time database such as [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) could also help.

Comment: This article:
https://chrisblackwell.me/server-sent-events-using-laravel-vue/
helped me setup Server-Sent Events in Vue. Hopefully, it can help you too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wanting to maintain state across your app, and each server event can affect multiple components. Use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html), the state manager for Vue (like Redux for React).

Your app will store the `auctionedItems` in Vuex (preferably inside in a ["module"](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/structure.html). Your components will use that Vuex state as a computed property, as if it existed in your component. You will write mutations (if sync) or actions (if additional async calls are needed) that will affect your state.

Example mutation could be:
`updateItem(state, newItem)`

Whenever your server pushes that event to the client with the updated item, you call into vuex `store.commit('updateItem', itemFromServer)`, which updates the Vuex state, which then propagates throughout your Vue App affecting any component using that state.

Client to Server is up to you. You could poll Express or use a WebSocket to push. This answer is just for your Vue client to handle that "server sent event".

Comment: but how does one access the store from the express server? I'm getting 'ReferenceError: store is not defined' from the server when trying to do store.commit('updateItem', itemFromServer)

Comment: Be sure to read the Vuex documentation. Their examples for syntax more accurate, though generally a component can access `this.$store`. You need to do some setup on your Vue instance as well to incorporate the Vuex store too.

Comment: I can get components to access the store, but not the backend. Maybe I'm missing something - my Express backend doesn't know anything about Vue (I don't have any require(Vue) in the backend (it communicates with frontend via REST), and I assume it's supposed to stay like that as best practise from an architecture standpoint?

Comment: I would agree. I like to keep the API separate, rather then "server side rendering". Look at my answer again - you need to poll your REST API (or use a WebSocket to push data) and update your Vuex store there. Check the Vuex docs too. You will update the store by "committing a mutation" or by "dispatching an action, that ultimately commits a mutation". So set up something in your front end that GETs (or receives)  data from your API Server, and then put that new information into the Vuex store via `.commit()` calls, as defined in the docs.

Comment: Thanks clay, I think I know how to solve this now - I'll integrate socket.io to allow server to push data to the client.